# why do I have stackoverflow

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-overflow, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to get my Squares procedure to work properly but, I keep getting either a runtime error or compile time error (I've been working with visual studio 2010 on different computers btw)

runtime error = "stack Overflow"
compile time error = warning A4011: multiple .MODEL directives found : .MODEL ignored   4   1   Project

But I only have one `.model` directive.

Why is my stack overflowing? Even without allocating a stack I still get errors.

Here's my code (just ignore the fibbonacci and Prime procedures):

```
    Include Irvine32.inc

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

.data
welcomeMsg BYTE "welcome",0dh, 0ah,0
menu BYTE "Please choose from:", 0dh, 0ah,0
num dword ?
;CHOICES:
choice BYTE "Prime == 0",0dh,0ah,
"fibonachi == 1",0dh,0ah, "Calculate Squares == 2",0dh,0ah,0

.code
main PROC

mov edx, OFFSET welcomeMsg      ;prints welcome message
call WriteString

mov edx, OFFSET menu            ;prints message
call WriteString

mov edx, OFFSET choice          ;prints choices
call WriteString

call ReadInt                    ;recieves int from keyboard
mov num, eax                    ;mov eax into num
mov cx,0
mov eax,10

JCXZ L1                         ;jump to L1

Prime:
mov cx,0
JCXZ THEEND                     ; jumps to end of program

Fibo:
mov cx,0
JCXZ THEEND                     ; jumps to end of program

Squares:
;Squares PROTO
call Squares
mov cx,0
JCXZ THEEND                     ; jumps to end of program


L1:
cmp num,2 
JE Squares ;if num == 2 jump to label           ; jump to squares

L2:
cmp num,1 
JE Fibo    ;if num == 1 jump to label           ; jump to fibonacci procedure

L3:
cmp num,0
JE Prime   ;if num == 0 jump to label           ; jump to prime procedure


THEEND:


INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP




;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;fibb PROC              ;begin fibonacci
;var word 0
;var2 word 0
;mov ecx,eax
;mov eax,1
;mov var2,1

;Loop1:
;   mov var, eax
;   mov eax,var2
;   add var2,var     
;JCXZ Loop1

;mov eax var2

;ret
;fibbo ENDP

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Prime PROC             ;begin Prime
;ret
```

Comment: I'll comeback and clean this up, g2g

Comment: You should try running it through a debugger.  This will help you catch errors like what @Mike found.

Answer (score 3):

I was going to pass on this one but this caught my eye:

```
Squares:
;Squares PROTO
call Squares
```

So whenever it gets to squares, it will push the return address onto the stack and go to squares again. And again. And again... Until the stack runs out.

Comment: Thanks for help Mike I got my code working now. And thanks for editing the code Jester, I only now realize that some of code was cutoff. not that the code that was missing mattered in this case.